# Como estilizar um echo com CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

Por exemplo: quero exibir um número formatado do banco de dados:

```
echo number_format($saldo, 2, ',', '.');
```

Ai o echo escreve: 8.944.664,00

Quero saber como uso o css nessa condição... pra mostrar na parte da tela que eu quero, na cor que eu quero, etc etc.

Eu aprendi assim: `echo "<div class=\"saldo\">$saldo</div>";`

Ai eu pego a classe no CSS eu deixo da forma que eu quero, mas com o `number_format` não deu certo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Põe o conteúdo a ser impresso sob aspas simples, assim você pode usar aspas duplas facilmente no conteúdo:

```
echo '<div class="saldo">'.number_format($saldo, 2, ',', '.').'</div>';
```

Ou ainda dessa maneira:

```
echo '<div style="color:red">'.number_format($saldo, 2, ',', '.').'</div>';
```

Comment: Ahhh, deu certo! Valeu, muito mais simples assim também :)

Answer (score 2):

Já que o `echo` permite que vários parâmetros, pode-se usar da seguinte forma:

Primeira forma *(aspas e virgulas)*:

```
echo "<div class=\"saldo\">", number_format($saldo, 2, ',', '.') ,"</div>";
```

Segunda forma *(aspas e pontos)*:

```
echo "<div class=\"saldo\">". number_format($saldo, 2, ',', '.') . "</div>";
```

Terceira forma *(echo shortcut / short open tag)* PHP >= 5.4.0:

```
<?=number_format(12930, 2, ',', '.');?>
```

O `echo`, permite que lhe sejam passados vários parâmetros. A primeira forma forma seria a mais comum, porque quando se tem vários parâmetros, o normal é que sejam separados unicamente por vírgulas, e nesse caso seriam interpretados de forma prioritária. Mas o que se deve ter em conta é que o `echo` não é propriamente uma função, mas sim um construtor da própria linguagem.

A terceira abordagem, não precisa que lhe seja vinculado o `echo`, simplesmente a `abertura + variavel + fecho`.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar a extensão .phtml no seu arquivo e trabalhar como se fosse uma página html apenas coloque entre `<?php ?>` ou `<?= ?>` os códigos em php(back-end).

Comment: Bem lembrado de mencionar a saida do modo do PHP. Só faltou um exemplo na sua de como usar isso para o que ele quer (que é a função, e não a variável). Poderia explicar melhor sobre a necessidade da mudança de extensão? Acho que valoriza a resposta se conseguir clarear os 2 pontos.